# How to refer external class path to play framework application?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, playframework-2.1

I have a small play framework application, which will create a spark session with `enableHiveSupport()` option, so i have to refer the `hive-site.xml` configuration file to the application

**In eclipse** 
i am able to refer the configuration file hive-site.xml by choosing 
**`Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Add External Class Folder`**.

**In Play framework:**

i have no idea about how to achieve this case in play framework.

**Note:**

i have tried by adding the `hive-site.xml` file in **conf/** folder , **lib** folder etc. Nothing works.

Comment: Typically, src/main/resources will be on the build path

Comment: There is no folder called main in my play project.

Comment: I would expect the file to be in the classpath, once you add it to the `lib` folder (for a Play! application). How did you package and run the application to test it?

Comment: If you used a Maven project, you'd have src/main/java... Are you not using it, Gradle or SBT?

Comment: I'm using SBT @cricket

Comment: @stefanobaghino, I have tried by keeping in lib folder, I will check once again and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, then sbt uses the same directory structure as Maven http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Directories.html

Comment: @cricket_007 sorry, we have created the project using activator initially but later we switched to sbt to run the applications. So we have lib and libexec folder only. Is it making problem here?

Comment: **conf/** folder is where you are looking for. **conf/** is equivalent to `src/main/resources` and every file in  **conf/** folder will be added to the main jar file. You can check this after building your play project.

Answer (score -1):

Put it in some directory under your project(e.g. dir-with-hive) and then in sbt, you would write:

```
resourceDirectory in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "dir-with-hive"
```

it will add "dir-with-hive" and everything in it into jar and classpath in runtime